# onChange="this.form.submit()" for dropdowns

Tags: jquery

Is there a reason why I shouldn't use:

```
onChange="this.form.submit()"
```

instead of

```
$(function () {
        $("#dropdown").live("change keyup", function () {
            $("#theform").submit();
        });
    });
```

Someone said it the onChange method shouldn't be used. I'm trying to find out the logic behind it.

The script basically submits the form on dropdown option change.

Comment: You should not use `live()` either, because it is deprecated. `on()` is the good way to go.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Could you show how to do the same thing using on() please?

Comment: Read the [manual on live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It shows how to translate `live()` into `on()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, there is little difference.

The idea behind moving things out of inline `onChange=...` attributes is to decouple your JavaScript from your markup. Having JavaScript mixed inline with your markup leads to ugly pages which are difficult to maintain and debug.

Ideally, you should have a clear separation between JavaScript, CSS and HTML. Your functionality, style and structure should be as independant and decoupled as possible.